# How to keep fps rate constant in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

Working on a game for iOS, using the sprite-kit framework to build it. The game runs smoothly for about the first minute in a half (maintaining the 60 fps rate), but as the player progresses into the game, the frame rate slowly starts to decrease. With time it even drops as low as 8 fps. I thought this was a result of the added debris and obstacles in the game, so I made an effort to remove a lot of them from the parent after time. This is how the game is set up:

There are 6 `NSMutableArrays` for the different types of debris that fall in the game. This is the format for each of them:

```
-(void)spawnDebris6 {

    SKSpriteNode * debris6 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"debris6.png"] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
    debris6.zPosition = 1.0;

    SKEmitterNode *debrisTrail = [SKEmitterNode kitty_emitterNamed:@"Dtrail"];
    debrisTrail.zPosition = -1.0;
    debrisTrail.targetNode = self;

    [debris6 addChild:debrisTrail];

    debris6.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:25];
    debris6.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    debris6.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionDebris;

    //set up a random position for debris
    //RandomPosition = arc4random() %248;
    //RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 10;
    debris6.position = CGPointMake (302, self.size.height + 65);

    [_debris6 addObject:debris6];
    [self addChild:debris6];

    //next Spawn:
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                         [SKAction waitForDuration:deb6Time],
                                         [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris6) onTarget:self],
                                         ]]];

    if (_dead == YES) {
        [self removeAllActions];
    }

    if (debris6.position.y > 568) {
        [self removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

Each of the `NSMutableArrays` appear over time - The first one appears at 0s, 2 @ 10s, 3 @ 40s, 4 @80s, etc. And when a new one appears I've added code to make former ones appear less frequently and also removed some (to lower the frame rate) yet I still notice a slower frame rate after about 90 seconds.

I don't see why this would be affecting the frame rate as I've minimised the particle birth rate, and life span, and made an effort to delete and slow down spawn rates of the debris over time. Why is the FPS rate slowly depreciating?

If more info is needed please let me know and I'll update this post.

Comment: Using the SKEmitterNode takes a HUGE toll on the processor. I would recommend using them as sparingly as possible. If you have dozens of objects all using SKEmitterNode, that could well be your issue. I suggest you disable the SKEmitterNode for your objects and see what your FPS is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It is probably the SKEmitterNodes. Continue to play around with them and lower birth rates and life spans, maybe even range etc. If the problem persists, see if you can take them out. It may not look as good, but sometimes you have to sacrifice looks for functionality. Also I'd recommend maybe having the debris appear at different times and heights, so you still have a full screen, but also a smooth running screen.